# exec() just run when i access target php in browser

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec, mod-security

i use this code to run another php for some work (ffmpeg convert)

```
    $binpath = get_option('binpath','/usr/bin/php');
    $command = $binpath." -cli -f ".ABSPATH."/videocron.php";
    exec( "$command > /dev/null &", $arrOutput );
```

but when i upload a video and run this code don't convert video for ever.

but when i access to videocron.php from browser all videos i uploaded convert suddenly!!!

i use alternative exec function(`system();` `exec();` `passthru();` `shell_exec();`)
and i check videocron.php by readable function, it is readable.

even i change owner videocron.php to nobody user

in mod_security log i get this error:

```
[Tue Sep 20 23:01:11 2016] [error] [client 37.156.10.171] ModSecurity: Multipart parsing error (init): Multipart: Boundary not found in C-T. [hostname "codenevis.net"] [uri "/lib/upload-ffmpeg.php"] [unique_id "V@GAb38AAAEAAGrk2QoAAAAH"]
```

but even i unistalll mod_security it don't work automatically.

but in all don't convert video until i access to videocron.php from browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for huge help and help me by Patience & listening my question.
i solve it by install mysqli.

```
yum install php-pdo php-mysqli
```

and restart appache